# How to run DirectPlay in a Portable way?

Tags: windows-10, drivers

I've tried to run an old game which stated I must install DirectPlay.
But since I don't want to do that just for 1 game, [attached](http://ge.tt/1X0FARx2) is a Process Monitor log of everything this game tries run that doesn't end with "SUCCESS".

Is there any way to fool it into thinking DirectPlay is installed? That is, put certain DLL files in the game's folder, etc.

Alternatively, can anyone try to install DirectPlay and detail what does the installation actually do?

[image: Requiring DirectPlay]
[image: Install DirectPlay]

Comment: What you want is not possible.  However, Compatibility Mode can be used instead, select Windows XP or Windows 7.

Comment: Didn't work, it still asked for DirectPlay. If we know the details of the installation, then I hope there's a way to simulate it.